# Replacing characters in a string, with a set of characters inside of a map in Clojure

Tags: string, clojure

I have a function that takes in a string `s` and a map of characters `charmap`. If any characters in the string `s` are inside of `charmap`, replace the character with the value of the map.

**Note**, the keys in the map must be a string, rather than a char.

For example:

```
(replace-characters "Hi!" {"!" "Exclamation Mark"}) ;; => "HiExclamation Mark"
```

This is the code I am currently using:

```
(defn- replace-characters
  "Replaces any characters in a string that are mapped in the given charmap"
  [s charmap]
  (let [character-set (set s)
        characters (filter #(contains? charmap (str %)) character-set)]
    (string/replace s (re-pattern (string/join "|" characters)) charmap)))
```

However, I am getting a `NullPointerException` and I am seriously confused on why.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.indexOf(int)" because "s" is null
```

I would like to solve this in pure Clojure preferably, not Java, etc.

**Update**: So the code above works in the repl. Which is nice. But for some reason the following is causing the error:

```
(-> s
     (string/replace #"[:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]" "")
     (replace-characters charmap)) ;; Where charmap is a large map of key value characters.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expression that causes error:

```
(str/replace "Hi" #"" {"!" "Exclamation Mark"})
```

(`"!"` was replaced with regex to `""`, `character-set` has value `#{\H \i}` and `characters` is `()`, so pattern created with `re-pattern` is `#""`.)

Empty regex matches every space between letters:

```
(str/replace "Hi" #"" " ")

=> " H i "
```

So, `replace` is looking for replacement in hash-map `{"!" "Exclamation Mark"}`, but doesn't find anything- there is no key `""`:

```
(str/replace "Hi" #"" {"!" "Exclamation Mark"})
=> error

(str/replace "Hi" #"" {"" " "})
=> " H i "
```

One possible solution can be to simplify definition of `replace-characters` (this solution will work only for non-empty `charmap`):

```
(defn replace-characters [s charmap]
  (str/replace s (re-pattern (str/join "|" (keys charmap)))
               charmap))
```

Tests:

```
(replace-characters "Hi!" {"!" "Exclamation Mark"})

=> "HiExclamation Mark"

(-> "Hi!"
    (str/replace #"[:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]" "")
    (replace-characters {"!" "Exclamation Mark"}))

=> "Hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

i would just go with something as simple as this:

```
(apply str (replace {"!" "[exclamation mark]"
                         "?" "[question mark]"}
                       (map str "is it possible? sure!")))

;;=> "is it possible[question mark] sure[exclamation mark]"
```

or this way with transducers:

```
(apply str (eduction (map str) (replace {"!" "[exclamation mark]"
                                                "?" "[question mark]"})
                        "is it possible? sure!"))
```

or maybe like this:

```
(defn replace-characters [s rep]
  (apply str (map #(rep (str %) %) s)))

user> (replace-characters "is it possible? sure!" {"!" "[exclamation mark]"
                                                            "?" "[question mark]"})

;;=> "is it possible[question mark] sure[exclamation mark]"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`string/escape`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/escape) does exactly what you want:

```
(string/escape "Hi!" {\! "Exclamation Mark"})
;; => "HiExclamation Mark"
```

that function replaces characters using a map from character to replacement.

If you want to replace regexes or string you can use [`reduce-kv`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce-kv) in combination with [`string/replace`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/replace):

```
(def replacements
  (array-map
   "!" "Exclamation Mark"
   #"[:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]" ""
   #_more_replacements))

(defn replace [s replacements]
  (reduce-kv string/replace s replacements))
```

So you loop (in order, when `replacements` is an [`array-map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/array-map)) over the key and values of the replacements and apply them on the string `s` using `string/replace`.

```
(replace "Hi!" replacements)
;; => "HiExclamation Mark"
```

if the order of the elements in the `array-map` is reversed the substitution of the ! with `""` (since ! is in the regex) would succeed:

```
(replace "Hi!" (into (array-map) (reverse replacements)))
;; => "Hi"
```

Comment: This solution would work, but I need the keys in the map to be a string, `clojure.string/escape` does not work for strings as keys in my experience.

Comment: @RawleyFowler why would you encode characters as strings? Anyway, the other solution described in the answer (`(reduce-kv string/replace s charmap)`) works with strings.

Comment: Does Clojure allow multibyte characters to be represented via `\悪`? I have many multibyte characters that I need to map as well. That would be the main factor for me to use your solution.

Comment: @RawleyFowler yes: `(clojure.string/escape "悪悪" {\悪 "something else"}) ;; => "something elsesomething else"`